# Mobile Responsive using JS Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I don't understand how to make a 3 images columns in 2 columns on mobile. I found that there is an issue with JS. In JS there is a condition for minslide:3 and maxslide:3...

So that in mobile also it showing 3 slides.. how to make it to be visible in 2 slider.. I mean in 2 columns..

```js
$j('#slider-collection-product .slides').bxSlider({
  auto: false,
  pager: false,
  responsive: true,
  slideWidth: 500,
  slideMargin: 50,
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 3,
  moveSlides: 3
});
```

```html
<div class="category-body sub_category_16">
  <div class="slider slider-category">
    <div class="slider-clip">
      <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 1248px;">
        <div class="slider" id="slider-collection-product">
          <div class="slider-clip" style="width:100%;">
            <ul class="slides">
              <li class="slide">
                <div class="slide-image">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" data-src="images/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" width="225" height="225" alt="Bicolore Linen Sheet Set by Frette">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-content">
                  <h4 class="slide-title"><a href="#">Bicolore Linen Sheet Set</a></h4>
                  <p class="slide-price">€1,650 - €1,700</p>
                  <div class="promo_text"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="slide">
                <div class="slide-image">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" data-src="images/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" width="225" height="225" alt="Bicolore Linen Sheet Set by Frette">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-content">
                  <h4 class="slide-title"><a href="#">Bicolore Linen Sheet Set</a></h4>
                  <p class="slide-price">€1,650 - €1,700</p>
                  <div class="promo_text"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="slide">
                <div class="slide-image">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" data-src="images/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" width="225" height="225" alt="Bicolore Linen Sheet Set by Frette">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-content">
                  <h4 class="slide-title"><a href="#">Bicolore Linen Sheet Set</a></h4>
                  <p class="slide-price">€1,650 - €1,700</p>
                  <div class="promo_text"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="slide">
                <div class="slide-image">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" data-src="images/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" width="225" height="225" alt="Bicolore Linen Sheet Set by Frette">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-content">
                  <h4 class="slide-title"><a href="#">Bicolore Linen Sheet Set</a></h4>
                  <p class="slide-price">€1,650 - €1,700</p>
                  <div class="promo_text"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="slide">
                <div class="slide-image">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" data-src="images/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" width="225" height="225" alt="Bicolore Linen Sheet Set by Frette">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-content">
                  <h4 class="slide-title"><a href="#">Bicolore Linen Sheet Set</a></h4>
                  <p class="slide-price">€1,650 - €1,700</p>
                  <div class="promo_text"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="slide">
                <div class="slide-image">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" data-src="images/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" width="225" height="225" alt="Bicolore Linen Sheet Set by Frette">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-content">
                  <h4 class="slide-title"><a href="#">Bicolore Linen Sheet Set</a></h4>
                  <p class="slide-price">€1,650 - €1,700</p>
                  <div class="promo_text"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.slides -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.slider-clip -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.slider -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.category-body -->
```

Comment: you ever thought of using http://getbootstrap.com/?

Comment: **1)** Make sure your Stack Snippet actually provides a working demo, yours does not. **2)** You're using a third party library to create an image slider, you should probably mention that.

Comment: Also, why are you not setting `minSlides` to `2`? This [bxSlider demo](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides) clearly shows that it will use the `minSlides` value for smaller viewports and the `maxSlides` value for larger viewports.

Comment: @hungerstar Ofcourse but.. I tried using by giving 2 for minSlides.. In this case even in desktop view also its showing 2 columns..

Comment: @SagarDoddapaneni how wide is the container on desktop? If it's not wide enough to contain 3 slides then it's going to display 2. But none of us know that because you haven't provided a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Brute but probably most simple workaround would be to include media-query dependent javascript, and trigger different bxslider settings dependent on the width:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 900) {
    // scripts
}
```

OR:

```
var mq = window.matchMedia('@media all and (max-width: 700px)');
if(mq.matches) {
    // the width of browser is more then 700px
} else {
    // the width of browser is less then 700px
}
```

[Media Queries & javascript from sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/)

[Media Queries & javascript from modernweb](https://modernweb.com/using-media-queries-in-javascript/)